# EditText appear only when i clicked on ImageButton

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-imagebutton

I would like to make appear an `textfield` for put text inside when I click on a `Imagebutton` on my main page, I tried some ways to do it but my `textfield` appear every time like this and its not what I want

```
serv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.serverpref);
        serv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                txtServ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtServ);
            }
        });
```

how should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Set Visibilty of Your `EditText` inside `ClickListener` of Your `Imageview` like below code

```
txtServ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtServ);
txtServ.setVisibility(View.GONE);
serv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               txtServ.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

**EDIT :** make Your EditText visibility `android:visibility="gone"` inisde Your xml layout like this

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Comment: Ok,thanks :)  thats look great, but if i make it VISIBLE its mean it was Invisible before ? so, how to make it invisible at beginning then visible when i click?

Comment: set the `visibility=gone` in layout

Comment: Thanks thats perfect :) +++

Comment: @VictorAttilaBreelle happy to help you

Answer (score 2):

Make it 'gone' or 'invisible' in xml.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

Then make it visible onClick

```
serv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           txtServ.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

read [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) for Visibilty constant.

Comment: **`fill_parent`** is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

try this it will Work. initially set **visibility gone in your layout file**

```
txtServ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtServ);

    serv = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.serverpref);
            serv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                   if(txtServ.getVisibility() == View.GONE){
                        txtServ.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
                    } 

             }
            });
```

Comment: Its look great, but still  my txtfield is visible from the beggining, so maybe i have to put something inside thre xml for make it not visible at the beginning ?

Answer (score 1):

what you need is first define your edittext

```
EditText txtServ = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtServ);
```

then hides it:

```
txtServ.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

then in onClickListener, show it:

```
      serv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            txtServ.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```